# If $\lim_{r\to 0}f(r\cos(\theta ),r\sin(\theta ))=f(0,0)$, then $f$ continuous at $(0,0)$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R^2\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ s.t. $f(0,0)=1$. If for all $\theta \in[0,2\pi[$ we have $$\lim_{r\to 0^+}f(r\cos(\theta ),r\sin(\theta ))=1,$$ then $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$. True/False.

To me it's true, but in my solution they wrote that it's false, and I don't understand why.

Comment: It looks like it will be interesting to see the counter-example they thought of...

Comment: @user How did you "prove" the result holds? This is the piece of context that would make your question interesting...

Comment: @Did: I have a theorem in my course that says that if $\lim_{r\to 0}f(r\cos(\theta ),r\sin(\theta ))=\ell$ for all $\theta $, then $\lim_{(x,y)\to 0}f(x,y)=\ell$. I'm just using polar coordinates... Take for example $f(x,y)=xy$. Then, using polar coordinate $\lim_{r\to 0}f(r\cos\theta ,r\sin\theta )=\lim_{r\to 0}r^2\cos\theta \sin\theta =0$, therefore, $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)=0.$ What's wrong here ?

Comment: "What's wrong here ?" The "theorem" you quote.

Comment: @Did: Very strange ! I always thought that if the limit $\lim_{r\to 0}f(r\cos(\theta ),r\sin(\theta ))$ were independent of $\theta $, then $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)=\lim_{r\to 0}f(r\cos(\theta ),r\sin(\theta )).$$ But there is not such a result ? If not, in what polar coordinate are interesting ?

Comment: @Did: See for example the correction of the exercise 4)(b) page 4 here : http://mathaa.epfl.ch/prob/enseignement/analyse2/series/set4_sol.pdf

Comment: The fact that the result you have in mind does not hold is **proven** by some answers below (I hope you did read them, did you?). Re the correction of the exercise in your link, it uses a different result, which is that if $$|f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)|\leqslant g(r)\tag{1}$$ for every $(r,\theta)$, and if $$\lim_{r\to0}g(r)=0\tag{2}$$ then indeed $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)=0$$ Note that $(1)+(2)$ together are much stronger than the hypothesis that, for every $\theta$, $$\lim_{r\to0}f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=0$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is false. You are testing continuity only approaching $(0,0)$ along lines, while you can approach $(0,0)$ with a lot of other curves. Take
$f(x,y)=0$ if $y=x^2$ and $x\ne 0$ and $f(x,y)=1$ for all other points. Then $f(0,0)=1$ and $\lim_{r\to 0}f(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)=1$ since the parabola only intersects the line of slope $\theta$ at most in two points. But the limit does not exist since if you approach $(0,0)$ along the parabola you get $0$.

Comment: Lol. There should be a way to know if someone else is also replying to a question at the same time. Otherwise we all waste time writing the same thing.....

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following function:
$$
f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
0, &\text{if}\ y=x^2,\ x\neq 0,\\
1, &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
This function satisfies the assumptions but it is not continuous at the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Example: we define $f$ by

$f(x,y)=\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}+1$ if $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$ and $f(0,0)=1$.

Then for  all $ \theta \in[0,2\pi[$ we have $\lim_{r\to 0^+}f(r\cos(\theta ),r\sin(\theta ))=1$, but for $x>0$:

$f(x, \sqrt{x})=\frac{3}{2} \to \frac{3}{2} \ne 1 =f(0,0)$  for $x \to 0$.

$f$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: Something I don't understand : when can we use polar coordinate to compute limits ?